# One word for students, faculty and staff at a university

Tags: single-word-requests

What word is used to include students, faculty and staff at a university?

Comment: In some places, this is called the "university community."  However, this term is imperfect, since it sometimes includes residents of the surrounding town as well.  It is also not used the same everywhere.

Comment: Members of the university. Though in some locations this would not include staff.

Comment: @cobaltduck *University community* is usefully vague, but if the OP wants a term strictly for this subset, it may be too imprecise. My alma mater's "community" includes alumni, parents, donors, and "friends."

Comment: I don't think there is a widely used word. Phrases like *the whole of the university* and *all of us* are commonly used in communications from those in charge.

Comment: The definition of [academia](http://www.yourdictionary.com/academia) is the world within an educational community.

An example of academia is a college, its students, and its teachers.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? The other answer is asking for a hypernym for teaching faculty and researchers; answers might cover students at a stretch, but it's hard to see how they would include staff (which includes secretaries, student services professionals, admissions officers, and many others).

Answer (score 3):

Besides the aforementioned ***community*** suggestion (a good one, IMO), the only other single words that come to mind are ***population*** or the variation ***populace***.

As in:

> ***The entire university population was expected to attend the event.***

Answer (score 1):

This rather reeks of business jargon, but you could say "university affiliates," meaning all those who are affiliated with the university. I've seen that phrasing before in campus newsletters.

Comment: Companies/businesses have employees and customers, and, in some cases, suppliers, contractors/subcontractors, shareholders, and/or directors (as in “board of directors”), who might not be considered employees.  Businesses sometimes refer to these people collectively as *associates* (or *affiliates*).  It seems reasonable that universities would use the same terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is no such word.

'Academics' would include students and faculty but not, for instance, janitors or secretaries.

'Staff/employees' would include faculty, janitors and secretaries but not students.

'Gown' or 'gowns' might do it, but only as opposed to 'town'.

Comment: Would domestic staff, gardeners, handymen or even IT techs (who may well be graduates of the same university) be regarded as 'gowns'?

Answer (score 0):

The word **campus** is sometimes used to convey this, either as *the whole campus* or *campus-wide* or in combination with one of the other suggestions already made (especially *the campus community*).

This term helps distinguish the individuals who are physically present at the university—on campus—on a daily basis from other university stakeholders, such as trustees, alumni, and the greater community.

Examples of usage (all bolding added):

> Pray God will work across the **whole campus**, not just students.
> ([FacultyCommons.com](http://www.facultycommons.com/easiest-page/))
>
> I have been personally touched by it, and I believe that the **whole
> campus** -- students, staff, and faculty -- have been overwhelmed by
> this tragedy. (["From the President's desk", *INSIDE Chico State*](https://www.csuchico.edu/pub/inside/archive/00_10_19/04.presidentsdesk.html))
>
> [Resources for the **Campus Community** | Covenant College](http://www.covenant.edu/resources/students_faculty_staff)
> A collection of useful links for current students, faculty, and staff.
>
> More than 4,000 University of Michigan students and 1,500 faculty and staff members are being surveyed about sustainability issues in October as part of a groundbreaking, **campus-wide** initiative . . . . The questionnaires are being sent to a representative sample of the **campus community**. (["University of Michigan Surveying Faculty, Students, & Staff About Sustainability"](http://sustainability.umich.edu/news/university-michigan-surveying-faculty-students-staff-about-sustainability))

Answer (score -1):

Would *academician* make sense to you?

According to [Meriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/academician), it is

> a member of an academy for promoting science, art, or literature

Comment: Administrative staff are not members of the academy, and I would not include them among either *academicians* or *academics*.

Comment: I'm not sure this term would include the staff, which would include custodial, food service, medical, athletic coaches, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to include undergrads either, only research and teaching people.